# What's the difference of pronunciation of words 'ward' and 'word'?

Tags: pronunciation

What's the difference of pronunciation of words 'ward' and 'word'?

I searched them in the dictionary, and

(link: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ward)

word sounds like '\ˈwərd\', and ward sounds like \ˈwȯrd\

But I'm not sure how I can make different sound.

Could you give me any tip about this?

(I try to speak 'word' more strongly, then I felt like it sounds close to 'world')

Comment: There are accents where the difference is rather minimal like Boston.

Comment: The pronunciations of syllables with post-vocalic 'r' vary a lot from region to region.

Comment: In IPA terms, "ward" has /ɔ/ and "word" has /ɝ/. "word" does not have a schwa.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this for **word**

> **Bird** with a **w** instead of a **b**, **w**+**ird**

Some guidance, **Bird Is The Word** by the Trashmen, can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Gc4QTqslN4)

and this for **ward**

> **War** (as in battle) with a guttural **d** (as in **d**own) at the end, **war**+**d**

These pronunciations are for a **flat** accent sometimes termed **newscaster** or [**General American**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American), there can be regional differences but this is the most basic.

Answer (score 1):

This may come as a totally inappropriate method to teach you how to pronounce *'ward'*, but I'll try and attempt it anyhow. 
Do you know the legendary Aussie cricketer Steve Waugh ? Now just pronounce *'Waugh-ed'*. That is close to the actual pronunciation of *'ward'*. 
The pronunciation of *'word'* shouldn't be a problem and I'm sure its pretty easy for you. It sounds very similar to *'world'*, just avoid the "L" sound. 
Words that sound like *'ward'* that can help you how to pronounce it : **wand**, **Vaughan**(another cricketer to the rescue).

Comment: Could you add a note about which region's pronunciation you're describing here?